# How could I run a shell script with delay

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I basically want to run a script which is a server but with 10 second delay, it is because I need some stuff to run before this script.

The server is located in the folder `/etc/init.d` but basically to make it work I go to that path using the command line and I have to restart the server typing:

```
sudo ./znodejs.sh stop
```

And then I start the server again:

```
sudo ./znodejs.sh start
```

I would like to know if there is any way to run those commands with a delay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to make a script run on startup first make it executable:

```
$ sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/znodejs.sh
```

Then you can register the script to be run at startup:

```
$ sudo update-rc.d znodejs.sh defaults
```

(Edit)
original answer:

the sleep command sill pause for a given number of seconds:

```
sudo ./znodejs.sh stop
sleep 10
sudo ./znodejs.sh start
```

Comment: I think my question wasn't clear at all, the server starts automatically from the start, so I would like to create a script to run those commands with a delay. I don't want to type it in the command line every time my raspberry reboot.

So I tried to run it like this in the rc.local:

`(sleep 10; sudo /etc/init.d/znodejs.sh stop)`
`(sleep 10; sudo /etc/init.d/znodejs.sh start)`

Comment: @JorgeCordero I have updated my answer to show how to enable your script to run on startup

Answer (score 4):

The standard unix command for sleeping is called

```
sleep
```

to wait a second, use

```
sleep 1
```